# Unhandled Exception: Exception: Exception accoured: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPrIZ.png)
Unhandled Exception: Exception: Exception accoured: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Unhandled Exception: Exception: Exception accoured: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

my model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSi2i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFESL.png)

model array api[array img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMuh.png)

Comment: it seems you are getting string type data somewere in your api response and in your model class you have defined its as String.

Comment: Post the code of the Wisata model

Comment: your error is in ui_dart_state line 209, you're treating index as string.  maybe printing it without calling toString.

Comment: ouh, how to call array within array into model n api